# Fast ways to plot points in a list of lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset that includes `(x,y)` of nearly 30 different points named `"point_1"`, `"point_2"` and so on.  The following shows a sample of a list of lists that I have:

```
list_p = [['point_1',[2,3]],['point_2',[3,3]],['point_1',[2,4]],['point_3',[4,5]],['point_4',[4,7]]]
```

where the first element in each list is the name of a point and the second element is its `(x,y)`. I am wondering if it is possible to have a plot that each point name has its `(x,y)` colored differently than `(x,y)` of other points. I mean for example all `(x,y)` of `"point_1"` have blue color, all `(x,y)` of `"point_2"` have red color and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> ... is there a faster way to do this?
>   I mean for example creating different lists for different points in `list_p` and then coloring them?

Well, there is such a possibility but I'd leave to you the investigation of which alternative is faster... let's start with your list (note: I have added another `(x,y)` to `"point_1"`) and an empty dictionary:

```
In [56]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    ...:  
    ...: list_p = [['point_1',[2,3]], 
    ...:           ['point_2',[3,3]], 
    ...:           ['point_1',[2,4]], 
    ...:           ['point_3',[4,5]], 
    ...:           ['point_4',[4,7]], 
    ...:           ['point_1',[2,1]]] 
    ...: d = {}
```

To plot with `scatter` we need, for each point type, a list of `x`es and a list of `y`s, and for labelled data the natural choice is a dictionary

```
In [57]: for p, (x, y) in list_p: 
    ...:     xs, ys = d.setdefault(p, [[],[]]) 
    ...:     xs.append(x), ys.append(y)                                                                                                                      

In [58]: d                                                                                                                                                   
Out[58]: 
{'point_1': [[2, 2, 2], [3, 4, 1]],
 'point_2': [[3], [3]],
 'point_3': [[4], [5]],
 'point_4': [[4], [7]]}
```

Finally we can plot our lists — note that now ① it is possible to add appropriate labels to the point categories and ② the different colors for different categories are dealt with automatically.

```
In [60]: for p, (xs, ys) in d.items(): 
    ...:     plt.scatter(xs, ys, label=p) 
    ...: plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: @Patol75 Of course no black magic is needed if one uses a `defaultdict`, but plain dictionaries have already everything that is needed for this kind of stuff...

Answer (score 2):

An example solution using a dictionary to store the mapping between name and color.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_p = [['point_1', [2, 3]], ['point_2', [3, 3]], ['point_1', [2, 4]],
          ['point_3', [4, 5]], ['point_4', [4, 7]]]
nameCol = {'point_1': 'blue', 'point_2': 'red', 'point_3': 'green',
           'point_4': 'black'}
for name, loc in list_p:
    plt.scatter(loc[0], loc[1], color=nameCol[name])
plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list_p = [['point_1', [2, 3]], ['point_2', [3, 3]], ['point_1', [2, 4]],
          ['point_3', [4, 5]], ['point_4', [4, 7]]]
nameCol = {'point_1': 'blue', 'point_2': 'red', 'point_3': 'green',
           'point_4': 'black'}
for key in nameCol.keys():
    plt.scatter([value[0] for name, value in list_p if name == key],
                [value[1] for name, value in list_p if name == key],
                color=nameCol[key])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Dear Patol is there a faster way to do this? I mean for example creating different lists for different points in list_p and then coloring them?

Comment: `list_p = [['blue', [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]], ['red', [[3, 2, 1], [0, 4, -1]]]]`?

Comment: list_1 includes all point_1 in list_p. 
list_2 includes all point_2 in list_p and so on

Comment: Then a code which colors all points in list_1 blue, all points in list_2 red and so on

Comment: I have added an approach with list comprehension, not sure if that is faster though...

Comment: Thanks a lot Patol for your time and effort. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Patol for your time and effort. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

#Get list of distinct points
distinct_points = set([p[0] for p in list_p])
#Map each distinct point to a different color
map_color_points = {p:c for p,c in zip(distinct_points, cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,len(distinct_points)))}
for p in list_p:
    plt.scatter(p[1][0], p[1][1], color = map_color_points[p[0]])
    plt.annotate(p[0], (p[1][0], p[1][1]))
plt.show()
```

Result[image]